# windows can't find .exe when i make a batch file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

so I need to create a batch file so I can run a program at startup.
I looked online and found a very simple instruction to make a batch file.
I opened notepad and put

```
start "c:\windows\windows32\" notepad.exe
```

saved it and it works fine so set about making mine.

again in notepad.

```
start "c:\server\" fcserver.exe
```

get the error message that windows can't find the file, but it is definitely there. just to make sure the path was right I copied notepad.exe into the server folder which works.

```
start "c:\server\" notepad.exe
```

it just doesn't seem to see the fcserver.exe although I can see it and I can run it from CMD using the same path.

Answer (score 5):

`"c:\server\"` doesn't specify the path as you may think. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154090) to the question [Using the “start” command with parameters passed to the started program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154075/using-the-start-command-with-parameters-passed-to-the-started-program)

> START has a peculiarity involving double quotes around the first
>   parameter. If the first parameter has double quotes it uses that as
>   the optional TITLE for the new window.

The example with `notepad.exe` works because `c:\windows\windows32\` is in your `%PATH%`.

You should instead be using

```
start c:\server\fcserver.exe
```

or if you need to quote the path

```
start "" "c:\server\fcserver.exe"
```

The START parameter syntax is the following.

`start ["<Title>"] [/d <Path>] [/i] [{/min | /max}] [{/separate | /shared}] [{/low | /normal | /high | /realtime | /abovenormal | belownormal}] [/affinity <HexAffinity>] [/wait] [/b {<Command> | <Program>} [<Parameters>]]`

[image]

[Start - Documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770297(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: `start "" "c:\server\fcserver.exe"` would indeed be what the author should be using and `start /b "" "c:\server\fcserver.exe"` would run it within the same command prompt that is already open.

Comment: I went ahead and provided the full syntax list and a description of each of the parameters.  The information didn't warrant it's own answer.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you. Because of your input I decided to make this answer community wiki.

Comment: You didn't have to do that.  You recognized the problem you should get credit for it.  I just have OCD when it comes to answers.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I did want to. I'm glad you made the answer so much better and I felt making it community wiki was the right thing to do. Also because I quoted yet another answer.