# Trying to start an app, but doesn't work correctly

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm pretty new to PC with batch, so I don't understand this. I've been trying to open an app without admin privileges, because I might've forgotten the password to the PC, so I'm using a user profile. The command I'm using is this:

```
set __COMPAT_LAYER=RunAsInvoker
start Setup Project64 v2.3.2-202-g57a221e.exe
```

I don't know how to fix this, because when I run the command, it loads another cmd with the title being that. Someone please help me out!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [windows can't find .exe when i make a batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/1275152/windows-cant-find-exe-when-i-make-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the second line to match this:

```
start "" "Setup Project64 v2.3.2-202-g57a221e.exe"
```