# System can not find a file that exists

Tags: windows-10, batch

In my x32win10Prov2004, a batch file works perfectly, but in the x64, it says that it cannot find the file.
The batch command line is

```
Start "" "C:\Program Files\Macro Express Pro\MacExp.exe" /APrintScreen
```

which I modified to

```
Start "" "C:\Program Files(x86)\Macro Express Pro\MacExp.exe" /APrintScreen
```

for the x64 system.

What it says can not be found is "C:\Program Files(x86)\Macro Express Pro\MacExp.exe", but a simple
inspection of `C:\Program Files(x86)\Macro Express Pro\` shows that it IS there.

If [windows can't find .exe when i make a batch file](https://superuser.com/questions/1275152/windows-cant-find-exe-when-i-make-a-batch-file)
holds the answer, I can not extract it from there.

Comment: Could you please explain what x32 and x64 systems mean here?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author’s issue was caused by a typo in their script

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the problem is that there should be a space between 'Files' and '(x86)'.

Comment: @Hannu Not really a solution here because it's Microsoft who chose this particular name. I think I heard they had deliberately put a space in the default installation location (`Program Files`), exactly to force programmers to handle spaces in paths; but this may be just a myth.